# Allows to choose only one option switch button inside table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

What is the best or elegant way to validate state switch?

For example if I select the second option (NO), change the first option state (isOn to false) (SI)

I want to achieve that allows to choose only one option

I have this switch inside table view

```
extension QuestionListTableViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return answers.count
  }
  
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "answerListCell", for: indexPath) as! AnswerListTableViewCell
    cell.separatorInset.right = cell.separatorInset.left
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

    return cell
  }

  @objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch!){
    print("Table row switch Changed \(sender.tag)")
    print("The switch is \(sender.isOn ? "ON" : "OFF")")
  }
}
```

I load view from xib

```
class AnswerList: UIView {

  @IBOutlet weak var optionSwitch: UISwitch!
  @IBOutlet weak var optionLabel: UILabel!
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    commonInit()
  }
  
  func commonInit(){
    let viewFromXib = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AnswerList", owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    viewFromXib.frame = self.bounds
    addSubview(viewFromXib)
  }
  
  
  @IBAction func switchChangedState(_ sender: UISwitch) {

  }
  

}
```

[image]

Comment: Your UI isn't a function of your data. I suggest moving the state of your switches in a data model When the user taps on switch, change the state of the data model and reload your table. You can enhance the performance by reloading only the necessary cells, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to add a property in your view controller that would keep track of the selected switch

`var selectedSwitchIndex: Int?`

And in your `cellForRowAt` method, set the selected switch to On and keep other switches off.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "answerListCell", for: indexPath) as! AnswerListTableViewCell
    cell.separatorInset.right = cell.separatorInset.left
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    let isSelected = indexPath.row == selectedSwitchIndex
    cell.answerList.optionSwitch.isOn = isSelected

    return cell
```

And in your `switchChanged` method, set the `selectedSwitchIndex` property to switch index which is toggled and reload your table view.

```
@objc func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch!){
    // you would want to save the index only when its set to on
    guard sender.isOn else {
        // setting the selectedSwitchIndex to nil if the switch is turned off
        selectedSwitchIndex = nil
        return 
    }
    selectedSwitchIndex = sender.tag
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```